# Second order ODE complex root, real part changing sign

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have a second order ODE, with complex constant coefficients, and suppose I guessed a solution $e^{\gamma x}$ and got that $\gamma = \pm(-a + bi)$. Is it still true that a basis for the solution space is $e^{ax}\cos(bx),e^{ax}\sin(bx)$?

Do the solutions must be complex?

Answer (score 0):

The solutions are always linear combinations of $e^{γ_ix}$ (with polynomial factors, if necessary). For a conjugate complex pair, you can combine them to form real valued solutions. In the general case, that is not possible.